# How to add increment and decrement functions to this piece of a counter?

Tags: java, counter, increment, decrement

Essentially, I need help writing an increment and decrement code in my lab. I've managed to do the stuff beforehand, but I want to wrap my mind around what I'm doing with this. My first thought is creating some kind of for loop? Any ideas of how to go about this?

```
class IncreaseCount implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int counter=0;
        counter++; 
        label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
    }   
}

class DecreaseCount implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int counter = 0;
        counter--;
        label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
     }
}
```

Comment: `counter++; label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));` ?

Comment: I don't understand - what the loop you talking about? What are you trying to do? Could you provide more code or much explanation the problem?

Comment: Is the counter embedded into ActionEvent object?

Comment: Yes the code is embedded into an ActionEvent object. After getting JB Nizet's insight, for loops are not what's necessary here, I got my program to run, but it's not functioning properly. Every time I hit the Increment button it goes to 1, but if I press it again it just stays at one. If I press Decrement it just jumps from 1 to -1.

I'll edit the code above to look like what I have now.

Answer (score 1):

You're increasing/decreasing a local variable. So each time the actionPerformed is executed, the counter is initialized to 0, and then increased or decreased. The counter should be a field (attribute) of the class containing these two action listeners.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet! Works like a charm now :)